# Unicode characters not readable in downloadable csv file generated from mysql database

Tags: php, unicode, export-to-csv

I am trying to generate a csv downloadable file generated from mysql database using php script. It is working but the unicode characters in it are unreadable. The unicode characters are readable when I open in Notepad ++ . I read answers on this question but they did not help. Please help. Following is my code -

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );    
ob_start("mb_output_handler");

include("t/db_config.php");
$con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  //set_charset when connecting with database
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');

$data=array();

 $sql="SELECT s.t_id,s.t_text,p.user_name,p.description,s.time,p.place from 
 t 
 AS s INNER JOIN users AS p ON s.user_name=p.user_name order by s.time 
 desc";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array=array("Link" => $row[0],"Text"=>$row[1] , "User Name" => $row[2] 
  , "User Profile" => $row[3], "Time" => $row[4] , "Place" => $row[5]);
     array_push($data,$array);
  }
  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
    if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';
    if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || 
  preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
      $str = "$str";
    }
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // filename for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: text/csv");

  $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');

  $flag = false;
  foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      fputcsv($out, array_keys($row), ',', '"');
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
  }

  fclose($out);
  exit;
?>
```

This is a sample input which is also the desired output -

umeshdutt निर्दोष को सजा मिल रही है

But getting the following output after opening csv file in excel -

umeshdutt à¤•à¤®à¤¾à¤² à¤•à¤¾ à¤•à¤¾à¤¨à¥‚à¤¨ à¤¹à¥ˆ à¤œà¤¿à¤¸à¤®à¥‡ à¤¨à¤¿à¤°à¥à¤¦à¥‹à¤· à¤•à¥‹ à¤¸à¤œà¤¾ à¤®à¤¿à¤² à¤°à¤¹à¥€ à¤¹à¥ˆà¥¤

**Edit -**

## Mysql table structure with sample data

## Table t

1)t_id (primary).....|2).....t_text......|3)....time........|4)..user_name........
===================|=======================================================
1)bigint(20).......| 2) varchar (255)   | 3)datetime       | 4)char(20)
...................| 2) utf8_general_ci |                | 4)utf8_general_ci
===================|=================|=====================================
847589475442204000 | संविधान 'सुप्रीम' है | 3/31/2017 5:01:52 AM| kotians

## Table users

1) user_id (Primary) |    2)user_name   |     3)place     | 4)description
==================|================|===============|============
1) bigint(20)       |2) char(20)        | 3) varchar(30)   |4) varchar(200)
                  |2) utf8_general_ci |3) utf8_general_ci|4) utf8_general_ci
==================|================|===============|=============

2883542694        |    kotians     |   Adelaide    |  Engineer

Comment: Please improve your question (via an edit) by including a minimal sample input, the output using it, and the desired output.  This will help you to receive faster and higher-quality answers.  After providing a sample input, you can eliminate the code lines that query your database -- they won't help us anyhow.

Comment: @mickmackusa Added sample input, desired output and actual output. Please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full PHP code that ran successfully (admittedly, I didn't take the time to systematically remove `encoding` and `header` functions to see if it would still work with less code):

```
if(!$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db")){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ",mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
    $sql="SELECT
              CONCAT('=\"',t.t_id,'\"'),
              t.t_text,
              p.user_name,
              p.description,
              CONCAT('=\"',t.time,'\"'),
              p.place
          FROM `t`
          INNER JOIN `users` p ON t.user_name=p.user_name
          ORDER BY t.time DESC;";   
    if($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"website_data_".date('Ymd').".csv\"");
        header("Content-Type: text/csv");
        header('Pragma: no-cache');    
        header('Expires: 0');
        $out=fopen('php://output','w');
        fputs($out,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");  // Byte Order Mark
        fputcsv($out,["Link","Text","User Name","User Profile","Time","Place"],',','"');
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            fputcsv($out,$row,',','"');
        }
        fclose($out);
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error($con);    
    }
}
```

By default in Excel `t.t_id`'s big integer value will be displayed using scientific notation (`8.47589E+17`) and `t.time`'s format will become: `n/j/Y g:i:s`

To mask these default adjustments, I have wrapped the values in double quotes (`"`) and prepended each with `=`.

I recommend doing any db value cleaning/modifying inside sql because you can prepare specific columns to have known issues instead of iterating all values in the row.

"Byte Order Mark" was an essential addition to your original code.

It seems this can be written at least these three ways with the same effect:

```
fputs($out,chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
fputs($out,chr(239).chr(187).chr(191));
fputs($out,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");  // I chose the shortest one
```

References and additional reading:

- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
- https://www.skoumal.net/en/making-utf-8-csv-excel/

I've included several suggestions/refinements like:

- Check for non-false `$result` before continuing with csv generation.
- Added a couple additional header() statements to ensure freshness.
- `fputcsv()`'ed the keys array statically before looping.
- Simplied the process inside of the `while()` loop.

I used this data from these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `t_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `t_text` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_name` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `t` (`t_id`, `t_text`, `time`, `user_name`) VALUES
(847589475442204000, 'संविधान \'सुप्रीम\' है', '2017-03-01 05:01:52', 'kotians');

ALTER TABLE `t` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`t_id`);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `place` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `place`, `description`) VALUES
(2883542694, 'kotians', 'Ade\'laide', 'Engi\"neer');

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);
```

And this is a screenshot of the active cells in the generated CSV file:

[image]